# Xcode: How to enable try-catch for c++ code

Tags: c++, xcode

```
try
{
   Polymorphic * pb = 0;
   typeid(*pb);  // throws a bad_typeid exception
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
   std::cerr << "exception caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

But the try-catch not work when run on **ios** device. I found out something about **/Eh**, but how to set it in xcode project? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And "not work" means.....?

Comment: Are you getting errors? Is the code not running? run-time? compile-time? **Give us something to work with!**

Comment: Sorry, I mean the catch clause won't be executed.

Comment: Have the same problem. Catch is never entered.